# How to modify this code so fragments appear in another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I currently have an app where the first page displays fragments of a list of patient names.When I click "Add" button on any of the fragments and THEN click the FAB, it should bring me to another activity with fragments showing the patient name and cholesterol value but  **currently it just pushes these new fragments on top of the existing patient list fragments?**

I know how to start a new activity on click of the fab but no idea how to pass the fragments?In my main activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> result) {
        patient_list = result;

        patientListFragment = PatientListFragment.newInstance(patient_list);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_list_layout, patientListFragment).commit();

        testTV.setText("");
        fab.setEnabled(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "done!");
    }
}

public void handleFab(View view){
    monitor_list = patientListFragment.getMonitorList();

    if (!monitor_list.isEmpty()){
        MonitorListFragment monitorListFragment = MonitorListFragment.newInstance(monitor_list);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_monitor_layout, monitorListFragment)
                .addToBackStack("monitor-list")
                .commit();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in summary, do you want to transfer data between activities? If so, you can use Bundle.
@SookYeeLim